Does True Belief Negate Free Will?
How can we say we have free will to sin or to abstain from doing mitzvos, while simultaneously saying that we believe in perfect faith in the punishments and rewards promised regarding these actions?
Meaning if we truly believe "Be'emunah Shelema" that terrible punishments will befall us for violating certain averos then we are as free as someone who can perform an act for a fleeting pleasure, but which will subsequently result in indescribable suffering. Although that person is physically able to do what he or she wants, but the belief that is possessed with absolute certainty should make it impossible for any rational person to sin or to neglect a mitzvah.
A response to why God does not perform open miracles is that open miracles do not allow for free will (although that doesn't seem accurate based on many narratives described in Tanach). Similarly, if someone possesses true faith that should also not allow for free will.
It seems that true belief and free will are mutually exclusive. Is this what prompted the Talmud to say that one cannot sin unless he is overtaken by non-rational spirit ("Ruach Shtus")?

I seem to recall that Plato held that perfect knowledge equals virtue with Aristotle arguing. See this piece from R Meir Simcha https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/Meshekh_Chokhmah/Shemot/0#m6e0n6

@RabbiKaii The other question is about punishments negating free will. This question is about true belief in punishments negating free will.

@ba maybe that question should be closed as dupe of this one then!

@RabbiKaii These are clearly two different questions and neither is a subset of the other

@ba I won't argue with you as you've seen something I haven't. From what I can see, they may be different questions, but they will have very similar answers?

@RabbiKaii Likely, but irrelevant to the status of the question itself. For illustration, this is an answer to the other question that doesn't directly address this question, and it's not so difficult to think of a line of reasoning to this question that isn't applicable to the other question

Yes, which is why we must work on Emunah.
